# Vue call method inside api callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using a payment api and there is a callback method from the api that will denote about the status of the transaction.

```
  async makePayment() {
            this.$launchFlutterwave({
                tx_ref: Date.now(),
                amount: this.amount,
                currency: "KES",
                customer: {
                    email: "user@gmail.com",
                    phonenumber: this.user.phone_number,
                    name: this.user.name,
                    plot_unique_id: this.plot_unique_id
                },
                callback: function(data) {
                    
                    console.log(data);
                    this.registerPayment(data);
                },
                customizations: {
                    title: "",
                    description: ",
                    logo: "https://assets.piedpiper.com/logo.png"
                }
            });
        },

 async registerPayment(data) {
            console.log("hit");
            await axios.post("/api/flutterwave/register/payment", data);
        }
```

Inside that callback, I want to register a method

```
  callback: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.registerPayment(data);
     },
```

and then that method will post the received back data and other user specific data to the back-end

```
 async registerPayment(data) {
       console.log("hit");
       await axios.post("/api/flutterwave/register/payment", data);
  }
```

But when calling the method inside the callback I'm receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: this.registerPayment is not a function`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57377369/8172857

Comment: Your this is not referring to the write context.
You need to switch to an arrow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the context inside the callback is different:

```
callback: function(data) {
  console.log(this); // you will see registerPayment doesnt exist here
  this.registerPayment(data);
},
```

Why not use the `registerPayment` directly? You can do so with:

```
callback: this.registerPayment
```

If you still want to call `registerPayment` from within the `callback` you can use arrow functions to access the outside context:

```
callback: (data) => {
  this.registerPayment(data);
}
```